# Django: How can I include a ManyToMany relationship into a modelform correctly?

Tags: django, forms, model

I have a question/problem regarding a **ModelForm** I want to use in my Django application. When I call the corresponding website including the **ContactCreate-form** there only appears a DropDownBox to choose an *Address-object*. Instead of this I'd like to use the **AddressCreate-form** at this point to create one new Address-object.

Is there an easy way to do this?

***The model***:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=False)

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    address = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
```

***The forms:***

```
class ContactCreate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact

class AddressCreate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
```

***The view:***

```
def create(request, template_name)
    contact_create_form = ContactCreate()  
    context = {'contact_create_form': contact_create_form}
    return render_to_response(template_name, 
                          context, 
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You need [inline modelformsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: I thought inline modelformsets work only for ForeignKey relations?! I will try this today

Comment: I couldn't get it working so far: I get either the error 'Contact has no foreign key to Address' or the error 'Address has no foreign key to Contact'.